# running a python script with values from views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, view

I am trying to pass in a value i got in a views.py file in Django into another python script i wrote, but i have no idea how to do so. Here is my code from views.py file:

```
    def get_alarm_settings(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        alarm = Alarm.objects.all()[0].alarm_setting
        response = HttpResponse(alarm, content_type='text/plain')
        response_a = execfile('alarm_file.py')
        return response_a
```

I am trying to pass response into alarm_file.py, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: If the script is written in Python, why don't you just `import` the relevant function and call it?

Comment: I am fully with Blender, you should implement function inside alarm_file and use import alarm_file to have access to it

Comment: How would i make it so it has the same effect as python alarm_file.py??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per comments under the question, make function in alarm_file.py and import it. To make `python alarm_file.py` call do the same, use `if __name__ == '__main__':` an alarm_file.py. It will contain logic to run when called `python alarm_file.py`. Additionally, you can use `sys.argv` to get argument, passed in command line. For example:

alarm_file.py:

```
import sys

def do_something(val):
    # do something
    print val
    # return something
    return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arg = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        arg = None

    return_val = do_something(arg)
```

This will ensure that you can run simply: `python alarm_file.py some_argument`

In your view just import function from alarm_file and use it:

```
from alarm_file import do_something
...
        response = HttpResponse(alarm, content_type='text/plain')
        response_a = do_something(response)
        return response_a
```

Comment: Thank you, very understandable and solves the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **Popen** method of **Subprocess** module.

For Example:

```
process = Subprocess.Popen(['python','alarm_file.py','arg1','arg2'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = process.stdout.read()
exitstatus = process.poll()
```

In this example, stderr and stdout of the script is saved in variable '*output*', And exit code of the script is saved in variable '*exitstatus*'.

You can refer my blog for detailed explanation >>

http://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-run-execute-any-script-python-perl-ruby-bash-etc-from-django-views/

Answer (score 0):

You may use the process-response middleware to handle the response returned from the view method, more details could be found here   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-response

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass arguments using execfile(), if you want to call another instance of the interpreter and run the script, you should probably use subprocess.popen 
([suprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html))

Something like this:
subprocess.Popen(['alarm_file.py', 'arg1', ...], ..., shell=True)